# Speech volume of videos on VLC media player is too low on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, audio, vlc-media-player

I just noticed that when I updated to Windows 7, almost all my movies are unwatchable because the speech volume is too low.

All was fine with Windows XP SP3.

I have latest updates for Windows 7.

I have tried several solutions such as: control panel sound settings, vlc compressor. Yet, none seem to work.

They say its because of 5.1 and 2.1 audio system incompatibility or something. But no solutions worked so far.

I have:

- Windows 7 32bit. Latest updates.
- Sound card: SB Live! 24-bit. Driver version:  5.12.1.2020
- Two speakers.

I haven't touched my computer physically at all. These 5.1 sounds just broke after Windows 7 install.

Comment: Which outputs are you using on the card and into how many speakers?

Comment: Check the Tools menu > Effects and Filters > Audio Effects > Graphics Equalizer. You may need to uncheck "2 Pass" and "Enable".

Comment: Is Windows 7 32-bit or 64-bit? Which audio driver version are you using?

Comment: @and31415, Windows 7 32 bit. Latest updates. "SB Live! 25-bit" driver version: 5.12.1.2020 (driver date: 16.10.2009).

Comment: @mindthemonkey, I have two speakers, i havent touched the card or wires physically at all when i installed Win7.

Comment: @harrymc, it was unchecked by default (i had fresh install of VLC).

Comment: `They say its because of 5.1 and 2.1 audio system incompatibility or something.` It’s possible. My mother always complains that watching DVDs is a pain because they’re so quiet, so I explained that only those with surround sound are quiet because they are meant to be played on 5.1 speakers, not the two on her TV. Movies with stereo audio are nice and loud on her stereo TV. So, I tell her whenever she watches a DVD, to check if the movie has a stereo audio track and switch to that. `almost all my movies are unwatchable because the speech volume is too low.` *Almost* all? e.g., surround movies?

Comment: @Synetech, looks like i fixed the problem. was simpler than i thought!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like I fixed this problem on my own, in accident; simply by going to Windows 7 sound settings. This will not require any additional programs to work!

**Step 1**:
Right click speaker icon

[image]

**Step 2**:
Click "configure" button on your speaker device

[image]

**Step 3**:
Select stereo (or appropriate setting for you) and click next and then finish.

[image]

For some reason I had "7.1 Surround" selected by default! No wonder why it made my sounds broken in movies.

Comment: See, it was a surround-sound problem; the system was trying to send the sound to eight speakers instead of just two, so it was getting diffused—imagine sending the same level of signal meant for stereo speakers to all eight!

Answer (score 2):

There is always a workaround for generic low-volume sound problem that uses to work: [AC3Filter](http://www.ac3filter.net/wiki/Download_AC3Filter). It has so much audio controls that, if you are patient enough, you will probably solve all your low-volume issues.
In your case you just need to increase *Master* and maybe *DRC* control on AC3 Configuration:

[image: AC3Filter v2.6 - Increase Master (and DRC if needed)]
Even more: I have often used it to solve that stupid 5.1 sound behavior of so many movies that makes explosions and noisy sounds too high... and voices in conversations sound too low.
I have found it valid for most media player (BSPlayer, Windows Media Player... etc), audio player (WinAmp, iTunes... etc) and even most audio playing (Java, Flash... etc). A real must-have utility.
Of course, this is not solving the main problem (driver, hardware or Windows configuration) at all... but it is easy, fast and works!

Comment: Do i need to make own configuration for each movie? Can i just install that thing and be done with it forever?

Comment: I tried to change master/gain, and some other things, but it doesnt make it sound normal at all. Why do i even need separate program to make sounds working on Windows 7 anyway? Currently the only way for me to watch these movies is to re-encode them with handbrake to stereo 2.1 format. then the sounds are fixed.

Comment: Indeed, changes are saved for every movie you will play in a future.

Comment: Well, I have tested AC3Filter in many computers, and, as long as I remember, it uses to work. If your problem comes from the audio 5.1 output format, you could try the option "Output format" and select your 2.1 or another one.

Comment: You need a separate program to make sound work on Windows 7 because... you can not make it work! Of course that reencoding should solve your problem, but just installing AC3Filter is a lot easier.

Comment: i tried output format changes, but the sounds didnt get as good as it was before; i watched this one movie before with no problems on Windows XP. I managed only make the voices slightly more louder, but all in all, still unwatchable. The voices sounds like they are recorded in some huge room (a little bit of echo) and very far away. Do you think new sound card could also fix this problem?

Comment: I would try this: 1.- "Driver Genius Pro" if you have the possibility (not free, as I remember :-( ) to update drivers. 2.- Request Windows autoupdate audio driver (search for a new one via internet). 3.- Get back to an older version of your audio driver if you have the possibility. 4.- If your sound card includes some audio device, try playing through it (audio only goes out via HDMI cable or DisplayPort, I think).

Comment: 5.- If you are going to buy another sound card (we still can not know if this will solve the problem), you could maybe try some USB one. 6.- Try another video player, just to discard it: BSPlayer, Media Player Classic, or Windows Media Player. 7.- If you have some virtual machine (like Virtual Box), try playing the video through (inside) it. VMs use to have no issues with audio matters.

Comment: Speech is the key here. adjusting the AC3 filter really is a good answer.  The Center channel of many of the movies holds all the dialog, thats just not natural.  Adjusting the Center channel up, and outputting to stereo in the AC filter does solve it, if not re-map the whole thing.  MCP can also remap too.  If the Audio has reverb and other noxious effects , it can be caused by other filters in the sound cards features.  Given adjusting about 15 things, sound can be put back to normal.  There have been many versions of the AC3 settings, older codec settings (XP) were more simple.

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez, i just noticed that windows media player plays at least some of these videos much better than VLC. maybe older VLC could fix this ?

Comment: It is not impossible, @Psycogeek. I would give it a try, at least. And, if possible, report here so we all know what solution worked for you.

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez, noticed now that windows media player actually executes this AC3Filter program (it appears to system tray), but VLC doesnt. What could cause this?

Comment: Upsss... I think I was wrong in the beginning: AC3Filter does not work with VLC (http://www.ac3filter.net/wiki/AC3Filter:Compatible_players). It does only work for DirectShow media players. Sorry, friend, I was nearly sure that it worked, but it is obvious that I failed.

Comment: @SopalajodeArrierez, seems like i fixed it on my own, in accident. I was trying to make my sound recording settings work, but instead i found out fixing this problem first!